# Is there a consistent way to make Windows use forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Tags: windows, file, unix, backslash

I'd like Windows to use forward slashes like in UNIX instead of back slashes in the file paths. I have a several thousands of .hpp files which refer to each other and the paths are all using /. In Windows and in particular MS Visual Studio, the directories I'm setting to refer to a specific build which contains my files of interest use . How can I solve this conundrum? It'd be quite a task to go through each .hpp file and changes the / into ... Thank you

Comment: *It'd be quite a task to go through each .hpp file and changes the / into* This is what programmers write programs and scripts for.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your encouragements to write a script doing this job :p

Answer (score -1):

`\` is the native path separator on Windows, there no way around that.

A lot of places accept `/` as well, just try it. If it does not work then your only options are to switch to `\` or use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) or Cygwin.